# CMake Library Linking using two different compiler versions

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I am facing some issues when trying to compile a shared library using CMake on Ubuntu (16.04) and linking it to an executable compiled with CMake on CentOS (6.8).

The first CMakeLists.txt to create the library looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MyLibrary)

file(GLOB ${SOURCES} SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
include_directories(${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/include)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

which will create libMyLibrary.so

The second CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MyApp)

set(MY_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../build)
include_directories(${MY_LIB_DIR}/include)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++98")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../build/libMyLibrary.so)
```

Note that the library was built in `build` directory, while the final executable `MyApp` is built in a different folder. On Ubuntu this combination works, while generating the library on Ubuntu and compiling only the second part on CentOS throws `undefined reference` for every function defined in C++11 and not defined in the C++98 standard. In fact, this was initially the reason why I did this: to build the library (containing C++11) with a more recent version of g++, and link it to the executable on CentOS, where an older version, not supporting the standard, is available (I have no root access on CentOS).

I would like to know if what I am trying to do is even possible, and, if yes, what am I missing.

**EDIT** After the answer of Matthieu Brucher, I added the flag `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the first CMakeLists.txt file, in addition to the `-std=c++11` flag. This removed `undefined reference` errors, but stil keeps the following:

```
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >&&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char>>::operator bool() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_getval()@GLIBCXX_3.4.18'
undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_fini()@GLIBCXX_3.4.18'
undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_init(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.18'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with this is that the c++11 version has a different abi. If you want to compile c++11 with the old abi, add the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Then the undefined references should be solved.